# Parse webpage to feed into Telegram Telegraph create_page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, telegram-bot

I' making a Telegram bot who serves webpages via Telegram's "[Telegraph](http://telegra.ph/api)" service, so that I can read pages with instant loading.

Hence, I can save on mobile data and drop annoying ads on the way.

Because of this, I need a way to feed any webpage into [this library](https://github.com/MonsterDeveloper/python-telegraphapi)'s createPage method.

Problem is that webpages can contain whatever tags, while Telegraph only support these Html tags.

```
ALLOWED_TAGS = [
    'a', 'aside', 'b', 'blockquote', 'br', 'code', 'em', 'figcaption', 'figure',
    'h3', 'h4', 'hr', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 's',
    'strong', 'u', 'ul', 'video'
]
```

Since I'm a beginner, I tried a lot before asking here.

I tried with Beautifulsoup `get_text` method, but it trims ALL the tags.
It bothers me, because I still want to preserve some, such as `<img>`, `<a>`,`<b>`, because I want to still be able to see images,and links.

I also tried `html.parser` with python, but I couldn't just hack into it.

I also tried some online services, like [Mercury Spotlight Parser](https://mercury.postlight.com/).
Nice service, but it still keeps some unwanted tags like `<div>`.
I already did some hacking to get rid of these, but I think this service is a no go, because it gave me unicode "character not found" (u+FFFD) while parsing German umlaut character, like `Möglichkeit`.

My ideal solution would be a function, which takes the `ALLOWED_TAGS` as a whitelist, and then trims all the html tags not inside this list.

Does such library / function exist?

I'm working with Python3 on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and unlikely to attract any good answers around here. I strongly recommend taking a stab at writing the code yourself. People are much more willing to help fix or improve existing code than write it for you from scratch. Also, please clarify what you want to do with the tags you're discarding. Do you want to delete all of the content inside of them? Do you want to just pretend the tags didn't exist but keep the content? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should return all unique html elements if they ( and the elements inside them ) are in the `allowed_tags` list

```
def allowedTags(soup, allowed_tags):
    tags = []
    for tag in soup.find_all(allowed_tags) : 
        if all(t.name in allowed_tags for t in tag.find_all()) : 
            if tag not in tags and not any(str(tag) in str(t) for t in tags if t != tag) : 
                tags += [tag]
    return tags
```

Note that it can be very slow for large pages ( 4.5 sec for this page )
I tried with `tag.children` which reduces time to 0.5 sec , but i couldn't get accurate results

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems like this code keeps the unwanted tags, like the div one. Have you tested it?

Comment: You 'r right, it returns divs if they are inside `ALLOWED_TAGS` . It's a little more complicated than i first thought , i 'll update

Comment: Updated to return only `ALLOWED_TAGS` , but still getting some duplicates , working on it

Comment: It works! I can't thank you enough...I still receive garbage, but I could (I hope easily) get rid of it. At least it's a start, I can apply this function to every site and BE SURE to create the telegraph page, although I will still have to trim the menus and lists... Thanks!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, i'm very glad my code is useful. Still 4.5 sec for this page is too much. If you have any ideas to make this faster, i'll be happy to help